# Подсчет количеств значений в каждой последовательности

Tags: python

Мне нужно посчитать сколько в данном списке раз встречаеться True

```py
a = [True, False, False, True, True, False]
```

Вывод должен быть в формате `[1,2]` в смысле что если 1 true то 1, если 2 true подряд то 2.
В голову пришла вот такая несложная идея решения:

```py
li = []
count = 0
i = 0
while a[i] < len(a):
    if a[i] == True:
            count += 1
    if a[i] != True and count != 0:
            li.append(count)
            count = 0
    i += 1

print(li)
```

Но и это не получается совершить. В список перменная count почему-то заноситься не хочет, да и IndexError выкидывает, даже если поставить len(a) - 1

Comment: Сравнение `a[i] < len(a)` не имеет смысла.

Comment: Не забывайте отмечать и оценивать ответы. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

a = [True, False, False, True, True, False]
groups = [sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(a) if k]
print(groups)
```

> [1, 2]

Если вы хотите решить задачу "руками", то надо рассмотреть все возможные сочетания пар соседних значений и обработать нужные:

```
a = [True, False, False, True, True, False]
result = []
prev = False
for v in a:
    if prev and v:
        # ..., True, True, ...
        result[-1] += 1
    if not prev and v:
        # ..., False, True, ...
        result.append(1)
    prev = v
print(result)
```

> [1, 2]

Код можно упростить так...

```
result = []
prev = False
for v in a:
    if v:
        if prev:
            # ..., True, True, ...
            result[-1] += 1
        else:
            # ..., False, True, ...
            result.append(1)
    prev = v
```

... или так ...

```
result = []
prev = False
for v in a:
    if v:
        if not prev:
            result.append(0)
        result[-1] += 1
    prev = v
```

В последнем случае код стал короче, но объяснить его сложнее.

Comment: `groups = [sum(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(a) if k]`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, вы правы. У меня после `C` травма связанная с приведением логических значений к целым.

Answer (score 1):

Проще, надо чуть проще. Первое, по возможности не работайте с длиной списка, всегда есть возможность уйти за пределы. Поскольку вы все равно бежите по всему списку, так и итерируйтесь прямо по нему. Второе, не добавляйте лишних условий. Плохо читается и думается

```py
a = [True, False, False, True, True, False]

count = 0
result = []

for i in a:
    if i:
        count += 1
    elif count != 0:
        result.append(count)
        count = 0

if count:
    result.append(count)
```

в каждой итерации вы будете брать `i` из списка по порядку, которое будет равно True/False. Поэтому можно использовать `if i:` поскольку это будет эквивалентно `if True` и тогда ветка сработает, либо `if False` и тогда в эту ветку не пойдет

Comment: а что означает 'if i'?

Comment: @Mr.Marshal дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял задачу то как то так:

```
a = [True, False, False, True, True, False,False,False]
li = []
count = 0
i = 0
old = a[0]
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] == old:
        count += 1
    else:
        li.append(count)
        count = 1
        old = a[i]
    i += 1
li.append(count)    
print(li)
```

Вывод:

```
[1,2,2,3]
```

Comment: Надо только True

Comment: Не то решение, надо посчитать сколько раз подряд идет True и внести эти значения в список

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [True, False, False, True, True, False]

li = []
count = 0
for i in a:
    if i:
        count += 1
    elif count != 0:
        li.append(count)
        count = 0
if count:
    li.append(count)

print(li)
```

Comment: по сути это копия кода из [более раннего ответа Dmitry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1413534/386633)

Comment: @NowhereMan зато я написал этот код сам